# just copying from textview in API 7 in android?

Tags: android, copy

I want to copy text from a `TextView` to clipboard in API 7.

I have this xml file :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="15dp" 
        android:shadowDx="4"
        android:shadowDy="4"
        android:shadowRadius="20"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"

         />
```

`android:textIsSelectable="true"` has two problems :

1. Just works API 11 and higher
2. This code allows a user to cut from `TextView`, but when user cuts from `TextView` the app fails. Can I do something that the user can't cut the `TextView` ???

Comment: Cut the `TextView` means?

Comment: I know you shouldnt cut textview ... but maybe user make a mistake and press cut instead of copy .......... app will fail and i think it is very bad that your app fail for just a small mistake !!

Comment: Do you want to copy on a click or on long press?

Comment: I want to copy section of textview or all of that ..... on long press is better ..... please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your java code use this :

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        cm.setText(textView.getText());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**- Above code is for click;For long press use below code-
In your `onCreate` method register your `TextView` for a context menu-

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
registerForContextMenu(textView);
```

Then override `onCreateContextMenu` -

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    //user has long pressed your TextView
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Copy");

    //cast the received View to TextView so that you can get its text
    TextView textView = (TextView) v;

    //place your TextView's text in clipboard
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    clipboard.setText(textView.getText());
}
```

Comment: I added all of your code under oncreate method ................. "void is an invalid type for the variable onCreateContextMenu " appears ....... what can i do ????

Comment: No. Not all of the code. `onCreateContextMenu` is a separate method.It should be outside `onCreate`.

Comment: It works ..... but the User can copy just all of textview ................. I want allow to user if he want can copy section of textview .... maybe user want to copy for example some words not all of textview ???????

Comment: Where are you Mr @naddy

Comment: That is a separate question. Make it an another question.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742352/how-can-i-copy-section-of-textview-not-all-of-that-in-this-code)  is my question

Comment: @user3410344 Follow the link given in the answer of your separate question. The link has the support for older versions.

Comment: Can you answer [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744794/sending-some-words-from-a-textview-to-other-apps-like-viber) ????
excuse me ........ I am biginner .... bare me Mr naddy