# How can I copy Section of textView not all of that in this code?

Tags: android, copy

I have this code from Mr Naddy for copying textView to clipboard in API 7

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
registerForContextMenu(textView);
```

Then override onCreateContextMenu -

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    //user has long pressed your TextView
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Copy");

    //cast the received View to TextView so that you can get its text
    TextView textView = (TextView) v;

    //place your TextView's text in clipboard
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    clipboard.setText(textView.getText());
}
```

It works ..... but the User can copy just all of textview ................. I want allow to user if he wants he can copy section of textview .... maybe user want to copy for example some words not all of textview ???????

what should I do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this ?

```
TextView tv;
String stringYouExtracted = tv.getText().toString;
int startIndex = tv.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = tv.getSelectionEnd();
stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.subString(startIndex, endIndex);
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
```

found at: [Android: Copy to clipboard selected text from a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624763/android-copy-to-clipboard-selected-text-from-a-textview)

Comment: when you will click the link above you will see that you need to test it for android version

Comment: sir ... This code works when you add android:textIsSelectable="true"............ If you don't add , this code won't work ........ 
also if you just add android:textIsSelectable="true" and clear above code copy in clipboard works very well but in API 11 and higher ........... I am confuse ...... above code cause copy to clipboard or android:textIsSelectable="true"

Comment: It is very important for me that the copy paste work In under API 11